# Correctly Suppressing Warnings in DataTables?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I'm trying to correctly suppress warnings (alerts) in DataTables. The standard behavior of DataTables is to throw a javascript alert when an error occurs; however, this is currently inconvenient for me. I have been trying to convert the warning to a javascript error by

```
$.fn.dataTableExt.sErrMode = 'throw';
```

Which works correctly, but this stops the current javascript execution, which is not what I want. So, I wrapped the DataTables operations (init and changes) in a try-catch with no error handling; however, this also halts the javascript execution. (Tested on Chrome and Firefox)

My question is how do I go about getting rid of these errors/alerts for the purposes of debugging? I'm trying to debug other parts of my script, but these alerts keep on getting in the way.

Comment: The best solution will always be to validate the information passed to DataTables so that it won't have any warning to throw...

Comment: that extension didn't do anything for me...  did you ever find an answer to this question?

Comment: Need more info to be able to offer help.   Try posting your code in jsfiddle so that we can better understand the issue you are reporting.

Comment: Have made a late answer to this, because I have struggled with this issue myself and saw the question due to recent activity (an answer appearently deleted again) It is not the "correctly" way since there is no "correct" way or even a possibility hidden around in dataTables. It is simply how to get around the problem.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

**NB: This answer applies to dataTables 1.9.x!**

For `$.fn.dataTableExt.sErrMode` the only value there has any importance is "alert". It is "alert" or anything else. `sErrMode` is handled by the internal dispatcher function `_fnLog`, in v1.9.2 about line 4575 in `media/js/jquery.dataTables.js` :

```
function _fnLog( oSettings, iLevel, sMesg )
{
    var sAlert = (oSettings===null) ?
        "DataTables warning: "+sMesg :
        "DataTables warning (table id = '"+oSettings.sTableId+"'): "+sMesg;

    if ( iLevel === 0 )
    {
        if ( DataTable.ext.sErrMode == 'alert' )
        {
            alert( sAlert );
        }
        else
        {
            throw new Error(sAlert);
        }
        return;
    }
    else if ( window.console && console.log )
    {
        console.log( sAlert );
    }
}
```

Unfortunelaty, there is no way to override dataTables internal functions, believe me - I have tried, not possible with prototyping or anything else. You can read the author Allan Jardines own comment to that [**here**](http://datatables.net/forums/discussion/1150/overriding-a-function/p1) :

> I'm sorry to say that due to how DataTables is constructed at the
>   moment, it's not possible to override an internal function using
>   Javascript outside of DataTables scope. This is something that will be
>   addressed whenever I get around to doing the 2.x series (which might
>   be a while off!) - but at present you would need to alter the core.

One could think that : *Hey, perhaps the iLevel-flag can be changed somewhere in the settings*? Again, unfortunately no. `iLevel` is hardcoded in each internal call to `_fnLog`.

It is somehow disappointing we have to choose between ugly alerts and completely halt of execution, because an error is thrown. A simply override of `window.onerror` does not work either. The solution is to modify `_fnLog`, simply comment out the line where the custom error is thrown :

```
else
{
  // throw new Error(sAlert); <-- comment this line
}
```

And the execution continues if you have `$.fn.dataTableExt.sErrMode = 'throw'` (anything else but "alert") and if errors occurs. Even better, one could need those thrown errors in other situations, set a flag outside, like

```
window.isDebugging = true;
```

and

```
else
{
  if (!window.isDebugging) throw new Error(sAlert); 
}
```

This is not a "hack" in my opinion, but overruling of a general not avoidable jQuery dataTables behaviour that sometimes is not satisfying. As Allan Jardine himself write in the above link :

> Why can't you just modify the source? That's the whole point of open
>   source :-)

Comment: Thanks. There was a suggestion in Datatable forum. https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/14680/warning-level-control-with-suggestion Was that implemented?  That appeared cleaner and will be out of the box. hope it can be done else your solution works well..

Comment: This became **official** and it is properly documented here: https://datatables.net/reference/event/error

Answer (score 21):

I modified the native alert using this closure function to redirect DataTables warnings to the console.

```
window.alert = (function() {
    var nativeAlert = window.alert;
    return function(message) {
        window.alert = nativeAlert;
        message.indexOf("DataTables warning") === 0 ?
            console.warn(message) :
            nativeAlert(message);
    }
})();
```

It restores the `window.alert` to its native function on first trigger. If you don't want it to restore to the original alert, just comment out the `window.alert = nativeAlert;` line.

Comment: This Solution works but seems to only work once per page load. i.e. multiple errors on that same page are not suppressed.

Comment: @michael-smith yes, that is explained in the post. You need to comment out the `window.alert = nativeAlert;` line.

Comment: You saved my whole day... Thanks

Answer (score 16):

Here's a solution [proposed here](https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/14680/warning-level-control-with-suggestion) that's slightly modified and works in v1.10.2 without having to change any vendor files:

```
$.fn.dataTableExt.sErrMode = "console";

$.fn.dataTableExt.oApi._fnLog = function (oSettings, iLevel, sMesg, tn) {
  var sAlert = (oSettings === null)
    ? "DataTables warning: "+sMesg
    : "DataTables warning (table id = '"+oSettings.sTableId+"'): "+sMesg
  ;

  if (tn) {
    sAlert += ". For more information about this error, please see "+
              "http://datatables.net/tn/"+tn
    ;
  }

  if (iLevel === 0) {
    if ($.fn.dataTableExt.sErrMode == "alert") {
      alert(sAlert);
    } else if ($.fn.dataTableExt.sErrMode == "thow") {
      throw sAlert;
    } else  if ($.fn.dataTableExt.sErrMode == "console") {
      console.log(sAlert);
    } else  if ($.fn.dataTableExt.sErrMode == "mute") {}

    return;
  } else if (console !== undefined && console.log) {
    console.log(sAlert);
  }
}
```

Comment: this is definitely the answer. The code appears to be included in all versions after 1.10 so just adding the `$.fh.dataTableExt.sErrMode = "console"` before adding a data table will fix the issue.

Comment: Thanks! This is simply what I needed.

Comment: My code does not execute AFTER error is written to console.

Answer (score 5):

As of DataTables version **1.10.15**, you can set **$.fn.dataTableExt.errMode** to '**ignore**' and it will silently ignore the error messages:

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $.fn.dataTableExt.errMode = 'ignore';
    });
```

**_fnLog** DataTables function has the following code :

```
        if ( type == 'alert' ) {
            alert( msg );
        }
        else if ( type == 'throw' ) {
            throw new Error(msg);
        }
        else if ( typeof type == 'function' ) {
            type( settings, tn, msg );
        }
```

The default value is '**alert**' which is problematic.

You can also set to '**throw**'. It will create javascript error, but will not do disturb the user.

'**ignore**' or any other values will just sliently skip the error.

Answer (score 4):

try this:

```
$.fn.DataTable.ext.oApi._fnLog = function (settings, level, msg, tn) {
    msg = 'DataTables warning: ' +
            (settings !== null ? 'table id=' + settings.sTableId + ' - ' : '') + msg;

    if (tn) {
        msg += '. For more information about this error, please see ' +
                'http://datatables.net/tn/' + tn;
    }
    console.log( msg );
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Let me add my 2 cents to davidkonrad's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22134916/188862) above.
One way of modifying `_fnLog` function without changing the file is to get reference to that method from Api instance in datatables settings:

```
$.fn.dataTableSettings[0].oApi._fnLog = function(settings, level, msg, tn) {
    // Modified version of _fnLog
}
```

Hope that this will be helpful for someone.