# DataTables Ajax error - Invalid JSON response

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, datatables

I'm using jQuery DataTables 1.10, the problem I'm having is the table loads the data and such from a service and the JSON is valid but after a few tries running it displays an alert periodically:

> DataTables warning: table id=reportsTable - Invalid JSON response. For more information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/1

So sometimes it runs perfectly fine then the alert just shows then I refresh and it loads the data. I researched online but to no success. What am I doing wrong?

Below is a screenshot of the error:

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: I did go to that url and followed their instructions but no success as i mentioned above.

Comment: You need to look at the json response in the debugger for a valid request and an invalid request.  Then compare the data.

Answer (score 1):

These kind of errors can come if your JSON response has invalid structure or null.
You can use tools like to verify your JSON response. e.g. JSONLint http://jsonlint.com/

Also, to disable error messages, you can change the opensourcedatatable.js script itself. 
Details: [Correctly Suppressing Warnings in DataTables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11941876/correctly-suppressing-warnings-in-datatables)